# Scala flyway migration marked as Success but there are no changes

Tags: scala, flyway

I'm new to Flyway. We are currently using version `6.5.7` of `"org.flywaydb"           % "flyway-core"`    in our `build.sbt`. The versioned migration also extends `BaseJavaMigration`.
The migration iterates over all rows in a table, and adds a field to json blob column. When I run the migration I first execute `info` to verify the migration is noticed, then `migrate` and finally `info` again to confirm the status of the migration.

I can confirm the migration is picked up and noted as `Pending` during the first `info`. Then after the migration is executed, no changes are applied, and also I don't see any info level logs from logback, which indicates that the migration didn't really enter the business logic of the migration.

The final `info` command then marks the migration as `Success`.

Here are some logs:

```
2021-11-29 16:33:35 +0000   | Versioned  | 42      | my migration name             | JDBC |                     | Pending    |
2021-11-29 16:33:35 +0000   +------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------+------------+
2021-11-29 16:33:35 +0000   dt=2021-11-29T16:33:35.138Z level=INFO thread=main logger=DbValidate Successfully validated 208 migrations (execution time 00:00.051s)
2021-11-29 16:33:35 +0000   dt=2021-11-29T16:33:35.147Z level=INFO thread=main logger=DbMigrate Current version of schema "public": 41
2021-11-29 16:33:35 +0000   dt=2021-11-29T16:33:35.151Z level=INFO thread=main logger=DbMigrate Migrating schema "public" to version 42 - my migration name
2021-11-29 16:33:35 +0000   dt=2021-11-29T16:33:35.396Z level=INFO thread=main logger=DbMigrate Successfully applied 1 migration to schema "public" (execution time 00:00.255s)
2021-11-29 16:33:35 +0000   dt=2021-11-29T16:33:35.498Z level=INFO thread=main logger=migrations Schema version: org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoImpl@fac39b2c
2021-11-29 16:33:35 +0000   dt=2021-11-29T16:33:35.503Z level=INFO thread=main logger=migrations +------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------+------------+



2021-11-29 16:33:35 +0000   | Versioned  | 42      | my migration name             | JDBC | 2021-11-29 16:33:35 | Success    |
```

It's super strange I'm not sure how to go about finding what could be causing this. I'm highly suspicious about the execution time `(execution time 00:00.255s)` , can you even open db connection that quick? Any suggestions how can I go about investigating this further?

Comment: I would guess the problem was not with **Flyway** but with your migration, care to show that code?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I will see if I can minimise it as there are important details in multiple files and a lot of the code has to be obfuscated as it's not publicly shareable.

Comment: One thing that occasionally happens is that people use an effect library like cats-effect and forget to call `unsafeRunSync` to actually perform the side effect. This is why I use the `-Wvalue-discard` compiler option.

Comment: By the way, a useful debugging technique in such cases is to create a minimal example that really should work, e. g. a migration that does nothing and only prints a lot message. Make sure that works, and then incrementally add more and more pieces of business logic while repeatedly checking that what you've added so far works.

Comment: whoops, typo. I meant to write “log message”.

Comment: We figure it out. Basically the body of the migration was returning a scala `Future` and the main thread was shutting down without waiting for that `Future` to complete. The solution was to wrap the body of the migration function inside `Await`. Thanks for the help @MatthiasBerndt and @Luis

Comment: Nice work finding the bug! I would like to point out that the aforementioned `-Wvalue-discard` compiler option would have issued a warning for this, so I would strongly recommend turning that on!

Comment: ha. someone has commented out specifically this `value-discard` in the code ... @MatthiasBerndt thanks for the tip!